# Did Christ intend giving the Holy spirit prior to his ascension in John 7:37-38?

Tags: john, christology, gospels

John 7:37-38 ESV

> 37 On the last day of the feast, the great day, Jesus stood up and cried out, “If anyone thirsts, let him come to me and drink. 38 Whoever believes in me, as[f] the Scripture has said, ‘Out of his heart will flow rivers of living water.’”

We are told that during the feast of Booths Christ cried out extending an invitation to those who are thirst.The text describes the invitation as referring to the giving of the Holy spirit,yet later in the same book it seems the coming of the the Holy spirit is connected to Christ ascension

John 16:7 ESV

> 7 Nevertheless, I tell you the truth: it is to your advantage that I go away, ***for if I do not go away, the Helper will not come to you***. But if I go, I will send him to you.

Did Christ intend giving the Holy spirit prior to his ascension?

Comment: It is one thing for an individual (such as David) to be aware of the ministrations of the Holy Spirit to himself, personally. It is quite another for the whole Body of Christ, under His Headship, to receive the anointing of the Holy Spirit which flows down from the Head to all the members (from the head, down the beard to the skirts of the garments, Psalm 133:2).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is in the next verse so let me quote the John 7:37-39 -

> **37** On the last and greatest day of the feast, Jesus stood up and called out in a loud voice, “If anyone is thirsty, let him come to Me
> and drink. **38** Whoever believes in Me, as the Scripture has said:
> ‘Streams of living water will flow from within him.’ ” **39** He was
> speaking about the Spirit, whom those who believed in Him **were later
> to receive**. **For the Spirit had not yet been given, because Jesus
> had not yet been glorified**.

Thus, there is nothing inconsistent between John 7:37-39 and the other references to the Holy Spirit in John 14:16, 26, 15:26, 16:7 that likens the Holy Spirit to an Advocate, Helper, comforter, or "paraklete" in Greek.

The Holy Spirit would come "with power" (Acts 1:8, 10:38, Eph 3:16, 1 Thess 1:5, Rom 1:4, 15:19, etc) only after Jesus' ascension as described in Luke 24:49 (NLT) -

> “And now I will send the Holy Spirit, just as my Father promised. But
> stay here in the city until the Holy Spirit comes and fills you with
> power from heaven.”

And also in John 20:21, 22 after the resurrection -

> Jesus said to them again, “Peace be with you. As the Father has sent
> me, even so I am sending you.” And when he had said this, he breathed
> on them and said to them, “Receive the Holy Spirit.

Comment: You may want to include: > Jesus said to them again, “Peace be with you. As the Father has sent me, even so I am sending you.” 22 And when he had said this, he breathed on them and said to them, “Receive the Holy Spirit.
(John 20:21–22, ESV)

Comment: @PerryWebb - thanks, Perry - good point

Answer (score 0):

John 7:

> 37 On the last and greatest day of the festival, Jesus stood and said in a loud voice, “Let anyone who is thirsty come to me and drink. 38Whoever believes in me, as Scripture has said, rivers of living water will flow from within them.” 39By this he meant the Spirit, whom those who believed in him were later to receive. Up to that time the Spirit had not been given, since Jesus had not yet been **glorified**.

i.e., glorified on the cross. The Spirit here refers to the special function of the Paraclete, the indwelling Holy Spirit. This is confirmed later in
John 16:

> 7 Nevertheless, I tell you the truth: it is to your advantage that I go away, for if I do not go away, the **Helper** [Paraclete] will not come to you. But if I go, I will send him to you.

Did Christ intend giving the Holy spirit prior to his ascension?

not in the special function of the Paraclete.

Answer (score -1):

The giving of the Holy Spirit to all believers as a component of their salvation was not given prior to the ascension.  However there is multiple pieces of new and old testament evidence for the presence and action of the Holy Spirit prior to Jesus' ministry, including creation (Genesis 1:2), Gideon (Numbers 6:34), and John the Baptist (Luke 1:15).  I hope this answered your question.  Keep studying :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> Now this he (Jesus) said about the spirit, whom those who believed in him were to receive, for as yet the spirit had not been given, because Jesus was not yet glorified. John 7:39

> Exalted then, to the right hand of God, he has received from the Father the promised holy spirit and has poured out what you now see and hear. Acts 2:33

There is no indication that we can conclude from John 7:37 that this concerns a *time* for this event. Other verses do give a time. The verses noted should be the primary reference for understanding this matter.

An invitation is not the same as the actual event and so no contradiction or uncertainty is evident.

Jesus in his pre-ascended, pre-crucifixion, mortal state of humanity is not able to grant such a thing as the spirit of God - unless God grants it through him as He did through the prophets etc. Once exalted, Jesus has the power within himself because God has given that to him.